# How to get latest github tag names in Golang?

Tags: github

I need to check the latest version in GitHub tags.
So far, I found one way that uses go-git library. I found this one https://github.com/src-d/go-git/issues/1030#.
Is there any other method to get the latest GitHub tags name?
I tried to find a good way for a few hours...
I really appreciate your comments or help!

Comment: Are you trying to programmatically get the latest tag from the current GitHub-hosted Git repository? Your question is not very clear.

Answer (score 1):

Just make GET request to [github REST API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/getting-started-with-the-rest-api).

```
# https://api.github.com/repos/<user>/<repo>/tags
curl https://api.github.com/repos/src-d/go-git/tags
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "name": "v4.13.1",
    "zipball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/src-d/go-git/zipball/refs/tags/v4.13.1",
    "tarball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/src-d/go-git/tarball/refs/tags/v4.13.1",
    "commit": {
      "sha": "0d1a009cbb604db18be960db5f1525b99a55d727",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/src-d/go-git/commits/0d1a009cbb604db18be960db5f1525b99a55d727"
    },
    "node_id": "MDM6UmVmNDQ3MzkwNDQ6cmVmcy90YWdzL3Y0LjEzLjE="
  },
  {
    "name": "v4.13.0",
    "zipball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/src-d/go-git/zipball/refs/tags/v4.13.0",
    "tarball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/src-d/go-git/tarball/refs/tags/v4.13.0",
    "commit": {
      "sha": "6241d0e70427cb0db4ca00182717af88f638268c",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/src-d/go-git/commits/6241d0e70427cb0db4ca00182717af88f638268c"
    },
    "node_id": "MDM6UmVmNDQ3MzkwNDQ6cmVmcy90YWdzL3Y0LjEzLjA="
  },
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

As @medasx indicated, you can get the tags of any GitHub project using the [GitHub REST API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/getting-started-with-the-rest-api).

It will return the tags in JSON format, which you can then analyze somehow.

For instance, if the tags are [Semantic Versions](https://semver.org/), you should be able to sort the tag names and get the most recent version.

For instance, to get an array of just the tags, using [JQ](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) for the json parsing:

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/src-d/go-git/tags | jq '[.[]|.name]'
```

To sort them and get the last one:

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/src-d/go-git/tags | jq '[.[]|.name|sort|.[-1]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Given an environment variable `GITHUB_API_SIMONE_TOKEN` you can get it with:

```
latest := fetchLatestTag("emicklei/pgtalk")
```

and the function definition:

```
/*
*

    curl \
    -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>" \
    -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
    https://api.github.com/repos/ORG/REPO/tags

*
*/
func fetchLatestTag(orgreposlug string) string {
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", fmt.Sprintf("https://api.github.com/repos/%s/tags", orgreposlug), nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("versioncheck failed:", err)
        return ""
    }
    req.Header.Set("Accept", "application/vnd.github+json")
    req.Header.Set("Authorization", fmt.Sprintf("Bearer %s", os.Getenv("GITHUB_API_SIMONE_TOKEN")))
    req.Header.Set("X-GitHub-Api-Version", "2022-11-28")
    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("versioncheck failed:", err)
        return ""
    }
    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        log.Println("versioncheck failed:", resp.Status)
        return ""
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    type tagEntry struct {
        Name string `json:"name"`
    }
    entries := []tagEntry{}
    err = json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&entries)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("versioncheck failed:", err)
        return ""
    }
    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        log.Println("versioncheck failed:", resp.Status)
        return ""
    }
    if len(entries) == 0 {
        log.Println("versioncheck failed: no tags")
        return ""
    }
    return entries[0].Name
}
```

which today gives:

```
v0.29.1
```